# Are uncontrollable modes with no real part stabilizable?

Tags: control-theory, optimal-control

so this is a simple question regarding stabilizability.

When I want to know if a certain uncontrollable system is stabilizable, I need to find the uncontrollable modes (also known as poles, or eigenvalues) and see if they are in the left-half complex plane.

But I want to know about those modes that don't have a real part, so they lie over the axis, these are usually named marginally stable modes. How do this modes interact with stabilizability?

Thanks!

Comment: The essence of stabilizability is that all uncontrollable modes are
stable and all unstable modes are controllable. If

$${\text{rank}}\left[ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
  {\lambda I - A}&B 
\end{array}} \right] = n$$

for all $\lambda$ with Re$(\lambda) \geq 0$ then system is stabilizable. That includes marginally stable poles.

Answer (score 1):

A state space model is called stabilizable if there exists some $u(t)$ such that,

$$
\lim_{t\to 0}x(t)=0\quad\forall\ x(0)\in \mathbb{R}^n.
$$

So if $(A,B)$ has marginally stable modes, which are uncontrollable, then those modes can never die out and therefore $x(t)$ will not go to zero for all initial conditions. Such a system would therefore not be stabilizable.

In order words, using the [Hautus test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hautus_lemma), $(A,B)$ is stabilizable if and only if,

$$
\text{rank}\left[\lambda\,I-A \quad B\right]=n \quad \forall \ \ \text{Re}(\lambda) \geq 0,
$$

where you only need to fill in eigen values of $A$ for $\lambda$, since otherwise $\lambda\,I-A$ is already full rank.